How to improve LSTM model performance for weather prediction?
I predict rainfall using observational data. There are a total of 87,070 data samples, but only 1,885 samples have rainfall.
And here is the LSTM model I am using:
class LstmModel(Model):
def __init__(self, Lstm_units) -> None:
    super(LstmModel, self).__init__()
    self.lstm_1 = LSTM(units=Lstm_units, return_sequences=True)
    self.lstm_2 = LSTM(units=Lstm_units, return_sequences=True)
    self.lstm_3 = LSTM(units=Lstm_units)


    self.den_1 = Dense(units=64, activation="relu")
    self.den_2 = Dense(units=16, activation="relu")
    self.den_3 = Dense(units=1)

def call(self, Input_md, training=False):

    x = self.lstm_1(Input_md)
    x = self.lstm_2(x)
    x = self.lstm_3(x)

    out_lstm = self.den_1(x)
    out_lstm = self.den_2(out_lstm)
    output = self.den_3(out_lstm)

    return output

The loss result after training is:

The test result is:

I thought the issue was that the samples with observed rainfall were too few compared to the total number of samples. So, I increased the number of rainfall samples by duplicating them until they make up 40% of the total.
And here is the result I trained:

The test result is:

It seems that the model has been optimized and learned the rainy samples better. However, it has led to overfitting. I would greatly appreciate any advice from everyone regarding my project. Thank you very much!
